# Hibernate: Parse/Translate HQL FROM part to get pairs class alias, class name

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Can anyone point me out, how can I parse/evaluate HQL and get map where key is table alias and value - full qualified class name.

E.g. for HQL

> SELECT a.id from Foo a INNER JOIN a.test b

I wish to have pairs:

a, package1.Foo

b. package2.TestClassName

It's relatively easy to do for result set

> ```
> HQLQueryPlan hqlPlan = ((SessionFactoryImpl)sf).getQueryPlanCache().getHQLQueryPlan( getQueryString(), false, ((SessionImpl)session).getEnabledFilters() );
> String[] aliases = hqlPlan.getReturnMetadata().getReturnAliases();
> Type[] types = hqlPlan.getReturnMetadata().getReturnTypes();
> ```

See [details here](http://www.hibernate.org/389.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hardly a good way of doing it, but it seems you can get the AST through some internal interfaces and traverse this:

```
QueryTranslator[] translators = hqlPlan.getTranslators();
AST ast = (AST)((QueryTranslatorImpl)translators[0]).getSqlAST();
    new NodeTraverser(new NodeTraverser.VisitationStrategy() {
    public void visit(AST node) {
        if(node.getType() == SqlTokenTypes.FROM_FRAGMENT || node.getType() == SqlTokenTypes.JOIN_FRAGMENT) {
            FromElement id = (FromElement)node;
            System.out.println(node+": "+id.getClassAlias()+" - "+id.getClassName());
        }
    }
}).traverseDepthFirst(ast);
```

So this seems to retrieve the alias-mappings from the compiled query, but I would be very careful using this solution: it typecasts objects to subclasses not usually visible to a hibernate-client and interprets the AST based on guessing the semantics of the different nodes.  This might not work on all HQL-statements, and might not work, or have different behaviour, on a future hibernate-version.

Comment: I generate dynamically HQL based on our internal API (criteria panes etc.) and for filtering conditions (i.e. WHERE part) need to know alias for each class in the HQL.

Comment: Looks like SqlTokenTypes.ALIAS_REF is not what I'm looking for. In my example above result will be "a, package1.Foo", but I need "b, package2.TestClassName" as well. I mean ALIAS_REF process "SELECT" part instead of "FROM".

Comment: Regarding your question of using Criteria API.
I have two reasons:
1. Legacy code
2. HQL allows you construct so called report queries (extract exactly data which you need and don't construct whole object). See link for details http://rongou.blogspot.com/2005/08/hibernate-report-query.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't know report quries, this was very interresting.  The whole point of Hibernate is ofcourse to map data from tables to objects, but for some applications tables are a better fit, and report-queries seems to fit exactly this.

Comment: Your are right. And I need that reverse engineering of HQL for controller of our reporting module.

Answer (score 0):

I found right solution for my question. Your original post was almost correct except that part:

```
if(node.getType() == SqlTokenTypes.FROM_FRAGMENT || node.getType() == SqlTokenTypes.JOIN_FRAGMENT) {
 FromElement id = (FromElement)node;
 System.out.println(node+": "+id.getClassAlias()+" - "+id.getClassName());
}
```

Please correct your answer answer and I accept it.