# HQL to SQL translation - defining meanful alias for columns

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, translation, alias

I have tricki problem:

When I translate a HQL to SQL (using `org.hibernate.hql.spi.QueryTranslator`) i got a valid SQL.
[Hibernate: Parse/Translate HQL FROM part to get pairs class alias, class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324105/hibernate-parse-translate-hql-from-part-to-get-pairs-class-alias-class-name?newreg=01c4ec8baff54ad89c5d0f0661808466)

It works as expected!

But, my problem is the transalation of the column aliases!

HQL to SQL

*) HQL for entity:Base

```
SELECT Base FROM Base Base
```

leads into:

*) SQL for entity:Base

```
select base0_.iD as id1_0_, base0_.comment as comment2_0_, base0_.creationDate as creation3_0_ from ...
```

You can see my problem:
The Alias of the columns are not intutive names:

```
base0_.creationDate --> creation3_0_
```

Expected:

```
base0_.creationDate --> creationDate
```

UseCases:

1. Creating Views for each entity, automatically
2. Better readabillity for our Database adminitrators

I have debugged hours and hours to find a solution to influence the mechnanism.

I hope some one has an idea how to solve this problem (whithout hacking)!

I know this is a not conventional question, so i would be glad, someone has an idea ;-)

Thanks, in advance

Andy

Answer (score 0):

The problem you faced is known as **Hibernate naming stragety**.

Here https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy you can find a deeper explanation on how to customize the generated column names by implementing the interface `PhysicalNamingStrategy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer, i'll try it immedaitly....

Comment: Glad to have helped you. Please upvote my answer if it works for you. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but it was not the solution, because now I can rename every column, table or schema, but not the alias in a select query.

I still get queries like this:

```
select base0_.i_d as i_d1_0_, .... 
from base base0_ 
left outer join campaign base0_1_ on base0_.i_d = base0_1_.i_d
```

but I would like to have a query without all this "1_0" etc.

```
select base.i_d as i_d, .... 
from base base 
left outer join campaign base on base.i_d = campaign.i_d ...
```

I want to use the translated queries to create views for all entities:

[resulting view and columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xliuP.png)

You can see, column names are not very useful ;-)

Does anyone have any idea, without string substitution or modifying the SQL AST?